# C# List<baseClass> - any way to store inherited classes within, too?

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

I am trying to create a simple "inventory" of items, much like in any RPG. I have *very basic* classes made, which have properties.

Anyway, I have a base class of `item` and inheriting from that is `weapon`. `item` has properties (name, value, weight, "important item") that are also used within `weapon`, but `weapon` has extra properties (attack, defense, speed, handedness).

I've got the following code (sorry if the readability is horrible):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
     List<item> inventory = new List<item>();
     inventory.Add(new weapon("Souleater", 4000, 25.50f, false, 75, 30, 1.25f, 2));
                           //item--------------------------->  weapon--------->

     Console.Write("Name: {0}\nValue: {1}\nWeight: {2}\nDiscardable: {3}\nAttack: {4}\nDefense: {5}\nSpeed: {6}\nHandedness: {7}",
            inventory[0].Name, inventory[0].BValue, inventory[0].Weight, inventory[0].Discard, 
            inventory[0].Atk, inventory[0].Def, inventory[0].Speed, inventory[0].Hands);

     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is add a new `weapon` to the inventory, but the inventory is a `List<item>` type. I went out on a whim hoping that, due to it's inheritance, it'd be accepted. It was, but the properties specific to `weapon` aren't able to be accessed:

*('shopSystem.item' does not contain a definition for 'Atk' and no extension method 'Atk' accepting a first argument of type 'shopSystem.item' could be found)*

So, is there any way to achieve what I was intending here? Have an "inventory" which can store `item` objects, as well as `weapon`, `armour`, `accessory` etc. objects, which inherit from `item`?  It is also worth mentioning that I can access all of the desired properties if I declare the following:

```
weapon Foo = new weapon("Sword", 200, 20.00f, false, 30, 20, 1.10f, 1);
```

Many thanks for reading.

Here's the `item` and `weapon` classes, if anybody is interested:

```
class item
{
    #region Region: Item Attributes
    protected string name = "";
    protected int baseValue = 0;
    protected float weight = 0.00f;
    protected bool noDiscard = false;
    #endregion

    public item(string n, int v, float w, bool nd){
        name = n; baseValue = v; weight = w; noDiscard = nd;}

    public string Name{
        get{return name;}
        set{if(value != ""){
            name = value;}
        }//end set
    }

    public int BValue{
        get{return baseValue;}
    }

    public float Weight{
        get{return weight;}
    }

    public bool Discard{
        get{return noDiscard;}
    }
}

class weapon : item
{
    #region Region: Weapon Attributes
    private int atk = 0;
    private int def = 0;
    private float speed = 0.00f;
    private byte hands = 0;
    #endregion

    public weapon(string n, int v, float w, bool nd, int a, int d, float s, byte h) : base(n, v, w, nd){
        atk = a; def =d; speed = s; hands = h;}

    public int Atk{
        get{return atk;}
    }

    public int Def{
        get{return def;}
    }

    public float Speed{
        get{return speed;}
    }

    public byte Hands{
        get{return hands;}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

In order to access the properties specific to the inherited class, you need to cast to the appropriate concrete class type. So, rather than accessing `inventory[0]`, you need to access `(weapon)inventory[0]`.

Also, if you are performing common tasks that will have different implementations based on the underlying class, such as logging the values to the console (which I realize was done for testing, but is a good example anyway), you should implement an overridable method in the base class.

For example, in the base class:

```
public virtual void LogProperties()
{
Console.Write("Name: {0}\nValue: {1}\nWeight: {2}\nDiscardable: {3}\nAttack",
            this.Name, this.BValue, this.Weight, this.Discard);
}
```

And in the weapon class:

```
public override void LogProperties()
{
Console.Write("Name: {0}\nValue: {1}\nWeight: {2}\nDiscardable: {3}\nAttack: {4}\nDefense: {5}\nSpeed: {6}\nHandedness: {7}",
            this.Name, this.BValue, this.Weight, this.Discard, 
            this.Atk, this.Def, this.Speed, this.Hands);
}
```

Then, to access this:

```
inventory[0].LogProperties();
```

Comment: If I use `(weapon)inventory[0].Atk`, I still get the same error message.

Comment: Try using ((weapon)inventory[0]).Atk instead

Comment: Excellent! Please see my updated answer for an additional suggestion.

Comment: Using a static cast will fail on elements that types of item other than weapon.  An `InvalidCastException` will be thrown.  It may be better to use a dynamic cast.

Comment: Thanks, @competent_tech! I'll require a method like that for debugging, so that'll make calling those properties a lot easier.
@MonroeThomas So, it would be best to use a dynamic cast if I didn't know what type would be in, for example, inventory[3]? That would be a more likely context when this system is up and running.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the right thing by using a `List<item>` to store items and subclasses of items!

When you extract the item from the list, you just have to do a bit of work to test if it's a `weapon`, or some other kind of `item`.

To see if the element at position `i` on the array is a `weapon`, use the `as` operator, which will return `null` if the item is not the specified type (perhaps it is armour or some other type of item).  This is known as a `dynamic` cast.  It works even if the item is `null`.

```
weapon w = inventory[i] as weapon;  // dynamic cast using 'as' operator
if (w != null)
{
     // work with the weapon
}
```

Another way to do this is to check the type using the `is` operator before doing a `static` cast.

```
if (inventory[i] is weapon)
{
     // static cast (won't fail 'cause we know type matches)
     weapon w = (weapon)inventory[i];           

     // work with the weapon
}
```

Comment: Better alternative to the second test: `if(inventory[i] is weapon)`. But your first example (with `as`) is probably preferable anyway, as it avoids casting the object twice. :)

Comment: @DanJ Yep, thanks!  That also obviates the need for the null check.  Answer adjusted accordingly.  :)

Comment: That first example is exactly what I'll require soon enough, when I begin to dynamically add items to the `inventory` instance. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is where Linq can be your friend when dealing with polymorphism. The problem with casting items is when the given index isn't the correct type. (I.e. `inventory[0]` isn't a `weapon`, `(weapon)inventory[0]` will throw.)

You can avoid the exception by using:

```
var myWeapon = inventory[0] as weapon;
```

However then you will be doing #null checks everywhere. Using Linq you get a lot of flexibility:

```
var weapons = inventory.OfType<weapon>();
```

From here you can use `Where`, `FirstOrDefault`, etc. to find data you're interested or iterate over the weapons.

Comment: +1 This would be my approach, it limits how much of your code must be aware of the generic inventory. For example, you can write a method that acts on a `List<Weapon>` and pass `inventory.OfType<Weapon>()` into it. That method never needs to worry about the existence of other types of items in your inventory.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a common interface (eg. `IItem`) through which you query properties of the items, or implement a common base class, probably an abstract one, and use that as the type `T` of the `List`.
If using the latter option, be sure to override the functions of the base class where appropriate, polymorphism will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cast the value back to a `weapon` in order to access those properties, i.e. `((weapon)inventory[0]).Atk)`. Note the parentheses: casting has lower precendence than field access, so you can't write `(weapon)inventory[0].Atk`; that would be interpreted as `(weapon)(inventory[0].Atk)`.

You'll also need to distinguish between the different classes (for example, you probably also have a `armor` class). The simplest to do that would be to add an extra value on the base class `item` which tells you the actual type of the object, and then cast accordingly.

However, a better approach would be to use inheritance - let `item` define a series of methods which can handle all the generic stuff - e.g. displaying information about the item - and then override it in the inheriting classes. That is, instead of accessing all of that data directly, you call out to a method which combines it in a sensible way. For your particular example, you're converting the item to a string, so it would probably make sense to override ToString() - that means you would be able to do this:

```
Console.Write(inventory[0]);
```

and depending on whether that is an item or a weapon, the ToString() of the appropriate class will get called (normally, you'd have to call the method itself, but ToString() is special because all objects have that method, so Console.Write does it for you).

In your weapon class, you'd then implement the ToString method like this:

```
public string ToString() {
  //Put all of the data in here, like in your example
  return String.Format("Name: {0}\n...", name, ...);
}
```

Comment: I like that ToString method. However, what if I wanted to access just one of those properties (say, the .Atk property) to use in a mathematical formula? Would it be best to keep it the way it is i.e. `((weapon)inventory[0]).Atk`? The string I was making was just to test that the values were storing correctly.

Comment: @Deadrust: Yes, you can do that, and you can also do `weapon usedWeapon = (weapon)inventory[0];` and then access all the properties on usedWeapon without additional casting. You'd probably want to do that even earlier, e.g. storing the currently equipped weapon on a `player` or `unit` class, but RPGs vary on their approach to this.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you don't *have* to use ToString for this example. It can make just as much sense to define your own method and call that - it all depends on what you intend to do with your classes.